# Как в python 3 парсить данные из локальной сети по ссылке?

Tags: python, парсер, url

подскажите пожалуйста, как в python 3 парсить данные из локальной сети по ссылке формата http: //helpdesk.local.uralkali.com/maximo/ui/?event=loadapp&value=activity&uniqueid=397461&uisessionid=19831&csrftoken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx (в ссылке специально стоит пробел, чтобы она не сократилась и заменен токен). Сложность заключается в том, что я не знаю как работают локальные сети в принципе, и допустим по простой ссылке (не локальной), например https://google.com/ у меня получается парсить данные, а по локальной ссылке ничего не выходит. Если вдруг это будет полезно, то есть такой сайт uralkali.com, и он не локальный, а вот с припиской helpdesk.local. уже не получается перейти, так как это уже локальная ссылка. Парсинг с обычных ссылок я тестил с помощью библиотек urllib.request и bs4, так же я пробовал парсить тот же самый файл, который находится по локальной ссылке(http: //helpdesk.local.uralkali.com/maximo/ui.....) с помощью той же библиотеки bs4 и обычной команды open с указанием кодировки UTF-8 и парсинг отлично работал, но HTML-файл был заранее скачан, и передан мне, а мне необходимо без скачки, имея одну ссылку парсить все данные. Извиняюсь если где-то написал очевидное или в чем-то ошибся, просто я точно не знаю как все работает, и поэтому лучше написать лишнего, чем что-то не дописать. Исходный код, который парсит данные с HTML файла могу предоставить, если это нужно, но не вижу смысла, все равно с локальной сетью он не работает.

Comment: Кода нет. В чем проблема - непонятно.